# xml filter on nested object using ruby

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, xml-parsing, logstash, elastic-stack

I have below xml format log file

```
<QuerySiteInformation>
    xmlns="http://www.example.com"
    <Site>
        <id>abc-cde-fvvvv</id>
        <Item>
            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>
            <code>67448833344443</code>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            <reference>/</reference>
        </Item>
    </Site>
    <SiteInteraction>
        <InteractionItem>
            <Location>
                <id>8496940--2842047577555</id>
                <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            </Location>
        </InteractionItem>
    </SiteInteraction>
</QuerySiteInformation>
```

I am wanting to mutate the xml tag `<objectMessage>message in multiples lines</objectMessage>` into `<objectMessage>MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED</objectMessage>` ONLY when `<objectMessage>` tag is inside `<Item>` tag

I have below part of the config which can look through and mutate the xml into the the message that i want

```
<objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
```

config

```
filter {
 mutate {
  gsub => [
    "some regex pattern can do the xml tag filtering", "MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED"

   ]
 }
}
```

However, this will change all the `<objectMessage> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>` including the one outside of `<Item>` field

I know using ruby plugin can do a better job and shouldn't be using regex for xml parsing at all. but this is the closest i can land on so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to use the built in xml filter plugin, it is way more reliable and maintanable:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html

The following conf file will parse the XML and replace the values for the inner object:

```
input {
    generator {
        lines => [
        '<QuerySiteInformation>
            xmlns="http://www.example.com"
            <Site>
            <id>abc-cde-fvvvv</id>
            <Item>
            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>
            <code>67448833344443</code>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            <reference>/</reference>
            </Item>
            <Item>
            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>
            <code>67448833344443</code>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            <reference>/</reference>
            </Item>
            </Site>
            <SiteInteraction>
            <InteractionItem>
            <Location>
                <id>8496940--2842047577555</id>
                <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            </Location>
            </InteractionItem>
            </SiteInteraction>
        </QuerySiteInformation>'
        ]
        count => 1
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        target => "xml"
        store_xml => true
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}

filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      event.get("[xml][Site][0][Item]").each_with_index do |item, index|
        event.set("[xml][Site][0][Item][#{index}]", "REMOVED MESSAGE")
      end 
    '
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
          "host" => {
        "name" => "Mac-Studio.local"
    },
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2022-11-28T13:47:31.352282Z,
         "event" => {
        "original" => "<QuerySiteInformation>\n            xmlns=\"http://www.example.com\"\n            <Site>\n            <id>abc-cde-fvvvv</id>\n            <Item>\n            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>\n            <code>67448833344443</code>\n            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>\n            <reference>/</reference>\n            </Item>\n            <Item>\n            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>\n            <code>67448833344443</code>\n            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>\n            <reference>/</reference>\n            </Item>\n            </Site>\n            <SiteInteraction>\n            <InteractionItem>\n            <Location>\n                <id>8496940--2842047577555</id>\n                <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>\n            </Location>\n            </InteractionItem>\n            </SiteInteraction>\n        </QuerySiteInformation>",
        "sequence" => 0
    },
           "xml" => {
                "content" => [
            [0] "\n            xmlns=\"http://www.example.com\"\n            ",
            [1] "\n            ",
            [2] "\n        "
        ],
                   "Site" => [
            [0] {
                  "id" => [
                    [0] "abc-cde-fvvvv"
                ],
                "Item" => [
                    [0] "REMOVED MESSAGE",
                    [1] "REMOVED MESSAGE"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "SiteInteraction" => [
            [0] {
                "InteractionItem" => [
                    [0] {
                        "Location" => [
                            [0] {
                                           "id" => [
                                    [0] "8496940--2842047577555"
                                ],
                                "objectMessage" => [
                                    [0] "Internal> message shown here in multiple lines"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer for my problem, much appreciated!. can we use **2** filters? or we can indent the `ruby` code inside inside the first filter.

Comment: Yes. You can put both filters within the same clause.

Comment: humm, i just tested it with my local setup. template that i used is [link](https://github.com/jolacaleb/docker-elk-with-filebeat), i spin up the local required resource using the docker compose and then injected the data via a file on the same directory. but failed like below:
[ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ][main][4520a9adde6b2b1b77fd3e8f40d4ace0bde137673a0a904be3000a0776fe1fa1] Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass

Comment: [WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash", :routing=>nil}, {"port"=>56506, "xml"=>"Internal> message shown here in multiple lines", "@version"=>"1", "tags"=>["_rubyexception"], "@timestamp"=>2022-11-29T07:23:, "host"=>"gateway"}], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logs-01", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"t_NEwoQBKfNnMTUquHLQ", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [xml] tried to parse field [xml] as object, but found a concrete value"

Comment: I think the data shape you have is different to the example I attached. I would need to see how your actual conf file and data looks like

Comment: Here is the repo [link] (https://github.com/DesAWSume/docker-elk-with-filebeat)

Comment: I used below command to ingest the data into Logstash for processing
cat./log/conditional_node_filter.log | nc -c localhost 5000

Comment: I got it working!!! need to add the multiline if it is coming from a file

Comment: Trying to play with the ruby part, and wondering how do you change the opposite logic to Only keep the inner tag`objectMessage` if  it is inside `Item ` node. The Rest of the 'objectMessage' don't have this condition will be having "REMOVED MESSAGE" mutation

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by this. You can create a new question so we help more people.

Comment: yeap, this is the new one, hope it make senses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634899/xml-filter-on-nested-object-using-xml-ruby