# xml filter on nested object using xml + ruby

Tags: elasticsearch, xml-parsing, logstash, elastic-stack

I am a ruby newbie, I have below xml format log file

```
<QuerySiteInformation>
    xmlns="http://www.abc-dd-cfff.com/aws/elastic/azure"
    <Site>
        <id>abc-cde-fvvvv</id>
        <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
        <Item>
            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>
            <code>67448833344443</code>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            <reference>/</reference>
        </Item>
    </Site>
    <SiteInteraction>
        <InteractionItem>
            <Location>
                <id>8496940--2842047577555</id>
                <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            </Location>
        </InteractionItem>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
    </SiteInteraction>
</QuerySiteInformation>
```

Note: **Internal> message shown here in multiple lines** can be anywhere in the log file

I am wanting to mutate the xml tag `<objectMessage>message in multiples lines</objectMessage>` into `<objectMessage>MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED</objectMessage>` **ONLY** if `<objectMessage>` tag is outside of  `<Item>` tag

Like below

```
<QuerySiteInformation>
    xmlns="http://www.abc-dd-cfff.com/aws/elastic/azure"
    <Site>
        <id>abc-cde-fvvvv</id>
        <objectMessage>Internal> MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED</objectMessage>
        <Item>
            <id>e5753ead-d202-451e-92cc-ea49d0a6bdf5</id>
            <code>67448833344443</code>
            <objectMessage>Internal> message shown here in multiple lines</objectMessage>
            <reference>/</reference>
        </Item>
    </Site>
    <SiteInteraction>
        <InteractionItem>
            <Location>
                <id>8496940--2842047577555</id>
                <objectMessage>Internal> MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED</objectMessage>
            </Location>
        </InteractionItem>
            <objectMessage>Internal> MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED</objectMessage>
    </SiteInteraction>
</QuerySiteInformation>
```

I got a help from a lovely person with below logstash config

```
filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        target => "xml"
        store_xml => true
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}

filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      event.get("[xml][Site][0][Item]").each_with_index do |item, index|
        event.set("[xml][Site][0][Item][#{index}]", "MESSAGE HAS BEEN REMOVED")
      end 
    '
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Which will change the xml tag inside of the `<Item>` node

But this time I am wanting to play around with this new conditional xml parsing